# Youtube Earning Reports and Youtube CMS Account

Tags: youtube-api, youtube-analytics

I am trying to Fetch earning reports for my channel i created.
I have registered my self as a youtube partner, i have linked my adsense account to my channel.
Now, when i try to fetch the Reports for earnings, it shows me insufficient permission.
Somewhere i read, that i should use content owner reports, so i was trying to figure out my content owner id, 
i guess that is available on Youtube CMS Account, I guess, correct me if i am wrong.

So when i tried to open https://cms.youtube.com page, it gave me an error

Your Google Account is not linked with YouTube Content Manager. Please try a different account or contact your Technical Account Manager for assistance.

How to contact Technical Account Manager?

My Only need is to get the All the reports Including EARNINGS reports from API for my Channel.

Answer (score 0):

To get earnings reports, you have to be a content owner, kind of network which has content management system. So actually you cannot get such a report.

Comment: I am the content owner, but i dont have Youtube CMS account, so how can i fetch the earning reports?